# appserver/platform agnostic bayeux implementation

Tags: java, bayeux

Am planning to create a bayeux implementation (comet) i.e a charting application which pulls the data from server and updates the chart accordingly

But is there anyway I can create a platform agnostic bayeux implemenation

i.e if I develop for Weblogic will it work on Websphere too

Please let me know your thoughts

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CometD project provides a Bayeux implementation that is portable across servlet containers (Tomcat, Jetty, WebLogic, WebSphere, etc) provided that only HTTP transports are used (i.e. not WebSocket).

Many of the recent servlet containers now support Servlet 3, and CometD runs natively in any Servlet 3 compliant container.

See also the [section about configuring CometD for Servlet 3 containers](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_configuration_servlet3) and the [section about the JavaScript transports](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#javascript_transports) for disabling the WebSocket tranport (in case you do not deploy in Jetty).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested CometD version 2.4.0 on several servlet containers: it works on Tomcat 6 and 7, Jetty 7 and Websphere 8. But not on Weblogic 11 or 12.

Implementing Bayeux using [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) might be a way to create a really "platform agnostic bayeux implementation".